# Cannot break loop using cin.get to detect period

Tags: c++, get, cin

I am using cin.get for the first time to grab one char at a time into a string "word".  But for some reason I can't set the period as a quit loop command.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool isAlpha (char ch);
string replace (string ch);
bool sexist (string ch);

int main()
{
    // Exercise 2
    string word = "";
    string sentence = "";
    char next;
    cout << "Type your sentence " << endl;


    while(next != '.')
    {
        while(true)
        {
            cin.get(next);

            if(isAlpha(next)) // If alphabet then add the char to word
            {
                word = word + next;
            }

            if(isAlpha(next) == false) // If not alphabet then put the char back and stop getting input
            {
                cin.putback(next);
                break;
            }
        }


        if(sexist(word)) // If word is sexist, replace word
        {
            word = replace(word);
        }
        sentence = (sentence + " " + word); // Tacking on words to the sentence

        word = ""; // Resetting word
    }

    cout << "Word = " << word << endl;
    cout << "Sentence = " << sentence << endl;



    return 0;
}

bool isAlpha (char ch)
{
    if(isalpha(ch))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

bool sexist (string ch)
{
    if(ch == "he" || ch == "she")
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(ch == "him" || ch == "her")
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(ch == "his" || ch == "hers")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
string replace (string ch)
{
    if(ch == "he" || ch == "she")
    {
        ch = "he or she";
    }
    if(ch == "him" || ch == "her")
    {
        ch = "him or her";
    }
    if(ch == "his" || ch == "hers")
    {
        ch = "his or her(s)";
    }
    return ch;
}
```

To explain my code more: I am trying to grab a word at a time, by grabbing a char at a time, and changing any words that are "sexist" into "neutral".  After grabbing the word, if it is sexist I will change it, if not then I won't change it, and then add it onto a "sentence" string.  I want the last word with a period attached to it to break out of the outer while loop and go to my final output line.

But after trying different loops and different codes I cannot break out of that while loop.  Is it because of the get command?  I am very very new to C++ so I may not understand some basic rules.  I have tried using a bool to set the outer while loop to false when a period is detected in next.  I have tried using goto commands to goto the output outside of the loop.

Comment: Could not [reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46c47cc209c18102). I've fixed the uninitialized `next`, of course.

Comment: As a side note, it is easier to use non-gendered they/them/their than the cumbersome "he or she."

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen  Yea definitely makes sense, it's just part of my lab prompt.  I'm in a basic C++ course.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with you code (apart from your main question):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
```

`cstdio` is the c++ version of `stdio.h`. It's an error to include both - stick with the first when you need to include it, but in this case you don't need to since you don't use any relevant functionality in your code...

Then, why include all these headers? You don't use most of them.. you only need these:

```
#include <iostream> // for cout/cin
#include <cctype>  // the c++ version of ctype.h, for std::isalpha
#include <string> // for std::string
```

also DON'T use namespace std!! You will find many relevant posts in stackoverflow if you need to understand why.

Then, you don't really need an `isAplha` function, your own version does nothing more than `std::isalpha` so why not use this directly?

Then you have this:

```
string replace (string ch);
bool sexist (string ch);
```

First thing to note is that you're passing std::string by value which you shouldn't really in both cases. In the case of `sexist` you should pass by reference to const. But you don't really need two different functions for this.. you are duplicating code, I'd do something like this:

```
void replace (std::string& ch) {
    if(ch == "he" || ch == "she")
        ch = "he or she";
    else if(ch == "him" || ch == "her")
        ch = "him or her";
    else if(ch == "his" || ch == "hers")
        ch = "his or her(s)";
}
```

and then you could rewrite your loop in more idiomatic style, like this:

```
  while(next != '.') {
    while(std::cin.get(next)) {
      if(std::isalpha(next))
     word = word + next;
      else { 
       cin.putback(next); 
       break;
      }
    }
    replace(word);
  }
```

With this, if you only use input with just alphabetic values and period you'll be OK. The reason that you can't escape the loop is that when `std::isalpha` is false, you're putting back the character so it's re-read next time which will cause your program to infinitely oscillate between the same call to `std::isalpha`.. Consider that a space is NOT an alphabetic character.. so input such as `He is.` will ever-oscillate once the space is reached..

(by the way, once I used a debugger I've found this bug in 30seconds.. DO USE A DEBUGGER! it will simplify your coding life)

To avoid this you need a different approach to your program.. I'd suggest using `getline` to read lines instead of characters and then parse them, you don't really need to read character by character in your case, neither do you expect multi-line input. Let aside that I'd consider it erroneous to expect your clients to terminate all input sentences with a period for your program to behave correctly..

Comment: Hello Marinos, I believe you answered another one of my questions a week ago thank you.  Your answer has been very...eye opening.  The reason I did a lot of things in my code is because my instructor is asking for specific instructions (probably because it's a lot simpler and more fundamental than what most people would use for this program).  I thought that typing `.` would quit the loop before it deems isAlpha false and putback the character.  Thanks I will try all your suggestions.